# Сглаживание содержимого на прозрачном фоне Awesomium WPF C#

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf, awesomium

Использую в своем проекте сторонний браузер `Awesomium`, с поддержкой прозрачности. И когда я пытаюсь вывести текст на прозрачном фоне у меня выступают неровности.

[image: Неровности]
[image: Неровности]

Для `body`, установлено свойство `background-color: transparent`.

Как можно сгладить эти неровности

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, дело в алиасинге. Если так, то `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` должно исправить. / А вообще awesomium кривовато работает с транспарентностью (я ни в коем случае не пытаюсь никого заставить пересесть на другую платформу), но у Electron она работает по-лучше.